# QWebSocketServer send delayed

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

I have an image processing class with a QWebSocketServer in it. When I start processing an image, I send a START_PROCESSING message. When the processing is done, I send a RESULTS message. What happens is that the messages are both sent at the end of the processing, one after another.

In the first test I've just called the send function when they have to be called. Then I've tested an emit/catch signal approach, but without a further thread (emit/catch from same main thread); same result My idea is now to run a separate thread that catches the emit and send the messages. Can this be a good approach? Or am I just missing something regarding the message send "mechanics"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enter the event loop the QWebSocket won't send or receive anything.

Three options:

1. Put your image processing in a second thread.
2. Use a second thread for the QWebSocket. To avoid race conditions use the signal-slot-mechanism to send your data to the QWebSocket in the other thread.
3. Call QCoreApplication::processEvents() inside your image processing.

The first one is in most cases the best option. The second can be a good idea if you have heavy load on the QWebSocket. The third is an option if you have to be single threaded.

Comment: I think I go for option 2 (the one I was talking about in my post). Stupid question: how to put the thread in "wait state" for signals? Dumb option: put the thread on sleep for infinite time => problem in closing the thread!

Comment: You don't have to. If you don't overwrite run() the QThread starts its event-loop automatically and if you overwrite run() add at last line exec(). You have either to create your QWebSocket inside the thread or use moveToThread().